# devise routing error edit_user_registration_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise

I get the following error trying to access <%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path) %>.

```
Routing Error
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

routes.rb

```
xyz::Application.routes.draw do

root :to => "home#index"

resources :profiles 

devise_for :users

authenticated :user do
root :to => "home#index"
end
end
```

My routes are as follows:

```
root        /                              home#index
profiles GET    /profiles(.:format)            profiles#index
POST   /profiles(.:format)            profiles#create
new_profile GET    /profiles/new(.:format)        profiles#new
edit_profile GET    /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)   profiles#edit
profile GET    /profiles/:id(.:format)        profiles#show
PUT    /profiles/:id(.:format)        profiles#update
DELETE /profiles/:id(.:format)        profiles#destroy
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
root        /                              home#index
```

Thank your very much for your help!

Comment: The error looks like it's from the edit_profile route, not the edit_user_registration route. Is this supposed to be on the edit profile page, and if so can you show us how you're linking to there?

Comment: I added a link from a profile view as follows '<%= link_to 'Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path(current_user) %>' - the rendered link looks like http://localhost:3000/users/edit.10 (with current_user) and http://localhost:3000/users/edit (without current_user). i think devise is taking the profiles controller as resource... but how to fix this? the path i use to the edit profile page is <%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_profile_path %>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path) %>.
```

Isn't being passed an I'd

```
<%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path(@user)) %>.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the edit registration link, the reason is this in your routes:

```
edit_profile GET    /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)   profiles#edit
```

And the link to the profiles page:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_profile_path %>
```

edit_profile_path expects an id

You need to pass in the object on which you want to edit a profile:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_profile_path(@user) %>
```

Or, if you want profiles to only act on the current user, set it up in routes.rb as a singular resource:

```
resource :profile
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Solved it by editing routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  if Rails.env == 'production'
    default_url_options :host => "myserver.com"
  else
    default_url_options :host => "localhost:3000"
  end
```